# lxc-start: controller: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state “STOPPING” instead of “RUNNING”

Tags: 18.04, lxc

when i run the config file

config file

sudo lxc-start -n controller -d

it gives me this error

lxc-start: controller: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 842 Received container state "STOPPING" instead of "RUNNING"

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode

lxc-start: controller: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options

Additional information

lxc-start --version

3.0.3

uname -a

Linux shahrukh-VirtualBox 3.12.74-031274-generic #201705101001 SMP Wed May 10 14:04:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux